# Is it normal, that some companies just sign the txt file which contains the sha value of the program?

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, gpg4win

Scenario A: Suppose I have an .exe file, the provider offers a sha1 txt file with hash value and this txt file is gpg signed. So I check if the hash value matches the exe file and then download the key either from the keyserver or directly from the provider, check the fingerprint again and see if the txt file is signed correctly.

Scenario B: The provider offers an .exe file and a gpg signature, I can check the exe program directly with the sig file.

Are both scenarios equally secure?

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24224/signing-files-vs-signing-file-hashes

Answer (score 3):

In general, it's fine to provide a signed manifest file with hashes instead of individual signed files.  Kernel.org, along with many other projects, do this, often by signing the output of something like `sha256sum`.

If the key lives in a hardware security module, this can often have substantially better performance, especially when signing large files like software archives or ISOs, since typically the hardware security module has limited bandwidth and has to see all the bytes that are signed.  It can also be more performant for the end user if they must verify many files at once, because verifying the signature is more expensive than a simple hash and that operation needs to be done only once instead of multiple times.

In the particular case you mentioned, which uses SHA-1, this isn't secure, because SHA-1 is subject to collisions, and so a malicious distributor could distribute two versions with the same hash, one which is benign and one which is malicious.  In order for this approach to be secure, you need to use a cryptographically secure hash function, like one of the SHA-2, SHA-3, or BLAKE2 hash functions, and not something insecure like MD5 or SHA-1.

Comment: I see the second paragraph is really problematic. Providing a hash to verify the signature is not true verification. The verification must be performed on the message itself. During the signature or the verification, the HSM doesn't need the message, they only need the hash of the message that can be computed very fast on the modern CPUs. Besides your scenario in the third paragraph is weak that the malicious distributor can be caught. The scenario in my answer was more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

They are basically the same. On both scenarios, an attacker have to change two files to make you download a tainted executable. On scenario A, it's the executable and the text file. On scenario B, the executable and the HTML page.

On either case, the workflow is the same: you get the provided signed hash, the public key, and validate the signature. From the security standpoint, it does not matter if the signature is on the webpage itself or in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention who is an adversary and their capabilities;

> Scenario A: Suppose I have an .exe file, the provider offers a sha1 txt file with hash value and this txt file is gpg signed. So I check if the hash value matches the exe file and then download the key either from the keyserver or directly from the provider, check the fingerprint again and see if the txt file is signed correctly.

**If developer are Evil**

1. If they are evil developers they will make three versions of the software;

   - Good one does what as advertised, nothing malicious.
   - Bad one does harm, and uploads valuable information to a third-party website.
   - Sneaky one does do harm in a sneaky manner, silently disable your disk encryption or upload the data as a part of telemetry but encrypted.

     The Good and Sneaky one collides under SHA-1 which is already shuttered. The bad one doesn't collide with them.
2. They publish the good package under their name and do what as advertised no backdoor and no sneaky.
3. They hire someone from outside and hack the servers and upload the bad one into one server and the sneaky one to the others.
4. A good ITSEC notices the bad one and the Company published the hash of the good one ( maybe initially ) and everyone checks their system.
5. Some found their files are not good and this creates a storm and everybody update their software. Now, almost everybody has the sneaky one.

So you need a trustful company. Otherwise, it is disastrous.

**Attackers**

Well, it is also possible that the company is hacked and the file and signature were created by the attacker. Check the news!

If the attacker adversary cannot access the signature key, they need to break the second pre-image attack to find another executable file that has the same hash to upload into the servers. Currently, this is not possible even with SHA-1.

> Scenario B: The provider offers an .exe file and a gpg signature, I can check the exe program directly with the sig file.

A similar evil developer scenario applies here, too. The attacker's case is still the same.

> Are both scenarios equally secure?

If we assume that we have semi-honest company;

There is a small difference in the signatures; normally before the signature, input is hashed as a part of the signature scheme. Scenario A unnecessarily hashes the file before the sign. They will have different signatures and Scenario A has some CPU/bandwidth/storage cost penalties.

Apart from this, they are the same!

Why do you still use SHA-1? Drop it, use SHA-512, SHA3-512, Blake2b, etc.